# MS BotFramework logic for speaking/not speaking

Tags: c#, botframework, text-to-speech

The MS BotFramework seems to have some logic which results in the following behavior:
* if I speak to the bot (rather than type), it will respond with speech.
* if I type to the bot, it will respond only with typed text.

I am looking for the place in the SDK where this logic resides, and if there is a place to influence it? E.g. have the bot be silent, even if I spoke to it?

Comment: what language? c# or node?

Comment: Language is c#.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this shows up in a few different places, nearly all of which are "your" code.

In your bot, it's up to you to formulate a response to an incoming message. There's nothing "automatic" about this process. The SDK's have some basic channel feature discovery, but they're all there only to help the developer formulate a channel relevant response.

The exception is if you're using Adaptive Cards, and your card has [SSML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Synthesis_Markup_Language) on it. In that case, it's up to the client (Cortana, Web Chat, etc) to "render" the card according to your device capabilities - either as a card, or with voice instead.